# Converting UL to SELECT - grabbing 'data-attr' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on a mobile version of a market selector. Clicking on a continent shows available countries and then clicking on a country shows available languages.

Clicking on a language should then change the `href` of the button based on the original `data-val"http://linkhere.com"` that was in the li. - but this for some reason isn't pulling through.

I'm trying to set the `value` of the `option` according to what its' original `data-val` was when it was still an li, but it's not working as you can see from my **jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GM8v/**

How do I pull in that original data-val attr? what I have isn't working (line 68 in the jsfiddle).

EDIT: I've also tried data('val') - and this doesn't pull it through either.

Sorry that my code is such a mess, I'm still learning.

sample code here:

```
$('section ul', this.$element).hide();

// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo(".continents", this.$element);

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": $('.continents span.selected', this.$element).text()
}).appendTo(".continents select", this.$element);

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$(".continents li a", this.$element).each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
    }).appendTo(".continents select", this.$element);
});


$(".continents select", this.$element).change(function () {

    //get the value of the selected item
    var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

    //when the select changes, do this

    $("<select />").appendTo('.countries', this.$element);

    // Create default option "Go to..."
    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
            "value": "",
            "text": $('.countries span.selected', this.$element).text()
    }).appendTo(".countries select", this.$element);

    // Populate dropdown with menu items
    $(selectVal + " li a", this.$element).each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<option />", {
            "value": el.attr("href"),
                "text": el.text()
        }).appendTo(".countries select", this.$element);
    });

    $(".countries select", this.$element).change(function () {

        //get the value of the selected item
        var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

        //when the select changes, do this

        $("<select />").appendTo('.languages', this.$element);

        // Create default option "Go to..."
        $("<option />", {
            "selected": "selected",
                "value": "",
                "text": $('.languages span.selected', this.$element).text()
        }).appendTo(".languages select", this.$element);

        // Populate dropdown with menu items
        $(selectVal + " li a").each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            $("<option />", {
                "value": el.attr('data-val'),
                    "text": el.text()
            }).appendTo(".languages select", this.$element);
        });

        $(".languages select", this.$element).change(function () {
            var selectVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $('#continue', this.$element).removeClass('disabled');
            $('#continue', this.$element).attr('href', selectVal);
        });


    });



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `el` in jsfiddle is the anchor element, and the `data` attribute is set to the list item.

To read the value of the list item, when anchor is given, do this:

```
var value = el.closest('li').data('val');
```